# Pass parms to v-dialog instead route

Tags: vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js

I'm changing a part of my vue-application. Instead of open a new tab I like to solve that issue with a `v-dialog`.

At the moment, I route the `id` to the component like that:

```
menuActions(option, project) {
   switch (option) {
     case 'Edit':
       this.$router.push({ name: 'ManageProject', params: { id: project.id }, query: 'vue' });
       break;
```

Now I'd like to open that component in a dialog, but I don't know how to pass the `id`

```
case 'Edit1':
    this.showDialog = true;
    break;
```

Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object, store necessary information(s) in the component you are using that dialog, and you will have access to that everywhere including dialog.  There is no need to explicitly pass some value to v-dialog as it is part of some component.

Answer (score 0):

you can recover the param with : `{{$route.params.id}}`

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes